# ¿Cómo acceder a los datos de un objeto?

Tags: json

He intentado acceder al valor title dentro de query, estoy usando el API de Wikipedia, he intentado con:

```
query[search]
//También con
var obj = JSON.parse(query);
var nombre = obj['search'];
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código fuente de la petición con jquery

```
$(".searchBox").on("change", function() {
        var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val();
        var url = "https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srprop=snippet&format=json&origin=*&utf8=&srsearch=" + searchTerm;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data);
                //no funciona
                console.log(query[search])
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: agrega tu llamada a wikipedia, y haz un debug para var obj = JSON.parse(query);  alli veras la estructura y podras ver como navegar en las propiedades

Comment: @CesarRomero me salta el error: query is not defined

Comment: Entonces agrega el código de como realizas la petición a wikipedia. Estoy usando el ejemplo https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20page&format=json que retorna el json `var resp = {"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"217225":{"pageid":217225,"ns":0,"title":"Main page"}}}};`  y así obtengo el title `resp.query.pages[217225].title`

Comment: @CesarRomero He agregado el código fuente

Comment: `var search = data.query.search`

Comment: @CesarRomero Gracias me funciono, si gustas añadirla como respuesta para tus respectivos puntos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta de la API, la recibes a traves de la variable `data` por lo que puedes acceder a la estructura json de la siguiente manera `data.query.search` que es la parte de interés; desde acá queda un arreglo, el cual podrás seguir procesando

```
$(".searchBox").on("change", function() {
    var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val();
    var url = "https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srprop=snippet&format=json&origin=*&utf8=&srsearch=" + searchTerm;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            var search = data.query.search;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que verificar la estructura del objeto, segun la imagen tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
query:{
  searchinfo:{}, //Objeto
  search:[{}] //Arreglo de Objetos
}
```

Por lo tanto para acceder al dato que requieres lo deberias hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
query.search[0].title
```